# Access "item" label from within a "field" template in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a field that contains a number of nodes that should be rendered as tabs.

The markup consists of the tab controls followed by the tab content.
I have an overridden `field` template that renders:

```
{# Tab controls #}
<dl class="tabs">
{% for item in items %}
  <dd><a>Insert tab label here</a></dd>
{% endfor %}
</dl>

{# Tab content #}
<div class="tabs-content">
{% for item in items %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

According to the doccomments, items has only two attributes

```
* - items: List of all the field items. Each item contains:
*   - attributes: List of HTML attributes for each item.
*   - content: The field item's content.
```

The "tab content" renders perfectly. I have a template that renders the node as tab content.

I get the correct number of tab controls, because I am iterating through the items, but I cannot access the item label (title) to render the control correctly, because `item.label` does not exist.

I can think of two approaches:

- Create a hook to somehow add the node label to `item`.
- Create a two templates: tab controls and tab content, that both select the node items, but render either the controls or the content.

I'm not sure if either is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this in a preprocess function defined in your module or theme (suppose reference field is called `field_articles`):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function my_module_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  switch ($variables['field_name']) {
    case 'field_articles':
      foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
        if (!empty($item['content']['#node'])) {
          /** @var Node $node */
          $node = $item['content']['#node']; // This is referenced node.
          $variables['items'][$delta]['label'] = [
            '#markup' => $node->label(),
          ];
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Now, your field twig template will have `item.label` elements.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.